# Convert BiDirectional Graph Edges to Undirected Edges in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am using [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) to do the following: I have a directed graph *g* that I want to
transform into an undirected graph *h* such that *h* has the same nodes as *g* and *e*
is an edge in *h* iff *e* is bidirectional in *g*. For example, I want to transform:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph([("A", "B"), ("B", "A"), ("A", "C"), ("C", "A"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "B"), ("A", "D"), ("C", "D"), ("B", "E"), ("C", "E")])
```

[image: directed graph]

into

```
h = nx.Graph([("A", "B"), ("A", "C"), ("B", "C")])
h.add_nodes_from(["D", "E"])
```

[image: undirected graph]

What `f(g) = h` should I write in NetworkX? I think it's some combination of graph
views and filters, but I'm new to NetworkX so I'm not sure exactly what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by iterating over the edges of you directed graph and checking if the reverse edge exist with the condition `if edge[::-1] in g.edges():`. If the reverse edge exist, just add it your graph. See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Creating directed graph
g = nx.DiGraph([("A", "B"), ("B", "A"), ("A", "C"), ("C", "A"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "B"), ("A", "D"), ("C", "D"), ("B", "E"), ("C", "E")])

#Creating undirected graph
h=nx.Graph()
h.add_nodes_from(g)

for edge in g.edges():  
  if edge[::-1] in g.edges(): #check if reverse edge exist in graph
    h.add_edge(edge[0],edge[1])

#plot both graphs
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Directed graph')
pos1=nx.circular_layout(g)
nx.draw(g,pos=pos1,with_labels=True, node_color='tab:orange')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Undirected graph')
pos2=nx.circular_layout(h)
nx.draw(h,pos=pos2,with_labels=True, node_color='tab:green')
```

And the output gives:

[image]